# Searching in a hash map returns all values stored, not just the one that is searched for

Tags: java, hashmap

When Searching for a particular key (in this case a name) in my `HashMap`, it returns all the values stored in the `HashMap`, not just the one I am after.

Code for search functionality:

```
if (e.getSource()==btnSearch) {

    Set setSearch = hmap.entrySet();
    Iterator iterator = setSearch.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
         Map.Entry mentrySearch = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
         if(hmap.containsKey(txtSearch.getText())){
             txtOutput.append(" Search Returned Student " + mentrySearch.getKey() + " and their mark was: " + mentrySearch.getValue() + "\n");
         } else {
             txtOutput.append(" Student not found. \n");
         } 
    }
}
```

I'm new to Java so this small detail is annoying me, as my program is 90% done. I have a delete functionality that does actually work and only deletes the one key selected.

Comment: which line in above code snippet `returns all the values stored in the hash map, not just the one` ?

Comment: I was iterating the entire map, hence why it was displaying everything, It's been solved now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are searching for the key inside a loop that iterates over the entries of the entire Map (that's what iterating over `hmap.entrySet()` means). If all you need is to search for one key, get rid of the loop.

All you need is :

```
     if(hmap.containsKey(txtSearch.getText())){
         txtOutput.append(" Search Returned Student " + txtSearch.getText() + " and their mark was: " + hmap.get(txtSearch.getText()) + "\n");
     } else {
         txtOutput.append(" Student not found. \n");
     }
```

Or just assign `hmap.get(txtSearch.getText())` to some variable (I wasn't sure what type that variable should be) and check if it's null or not.

Comment: Wow I feel silly, thank you very much! Was much simplier to fix than I thought,

Comment: @RyanHuckerby please, accept the answer so people that search for it knows for sure that this solved your question/issue